# Creating new folders that have read-write access

Tags: java, permissions, directory

I am currently creating a directory based on file names and then moving the files into the new directories. At the moment i am creating the new directories fine using the following code:

```
String filename = filesInFolder.get(i).toString();
File fullPathFile = new File(filename.replaceAll("(\\w+)_(\\d+).*", "$1/$2/$0"));
fullPathFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Then i am trying to use `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to move the files to the new directories, the code is ok it seems but when i create the new directories, all the folders are set to `read-only` so i cannot move the files into the knew directories

So is there a way to set the folders to `read-write` when they are created?

Comment: Read-only directories? What operating system?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/564154/create-directory-with-write-permissions-for-the-group

Comment: ya, i am creating a new directory of folders and all the folders in the new directory have read-only access. i am using windows xp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `fullPathFile.getParentFile().setWritable(true)` before calling mkdirs() should do.
The method `setWritable (bool)` is a convenience method to set the owner's write permission for this abstract pathname. 
 Since is a File, you can apply it.

Comment: when I try to do this i get an error 'boolean cannot be dereferenced', it will let me add setWritable(true) after getParentFile() but it will not leave me add .mkdirs() after so, any ideas?

Comment: I'll look at the problem, but I tried it and it works. You should the API for more details. Do you mean that the method mkdirs() is no longer available? If I getting what you're saying, you are writing `fullPathFile.getParentFile().setWritable(true).mkdirs`? If yes, then its normal, because setWritable (bool) will return a boolean which tells whether the permission change failed or succeded.