# Spring Integration File Outbound folder permission

Tags: spring, spring-integration, adapter, integration, outbound

We are creating a folder structure and writing files to this newly created folder structure using data in the channel. The problem we have is that the folder is to be updated/deleted by another user. Is there a way we can set folder/file permission explicitly using SI file outbound adapter?

```
<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="fileLoggingAdapter" auto-create-directory="true" directory-expression="headers['FileDetails'].directory" 
            filename-generator-expression="headers['FileDetails'].fileName+'.csv'"    />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [no standard ability](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-writing) to do this in SI.

However, you can create your own message processing step and put it BEFORE your `file:outbound-channel-adapter`. It may be e.g. some transformer which takes your directory name from message header, [creates the directory with needed permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564154/create-directory-with-write-permissions-for-the-group) and resend message further intact.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to set permissions when creating the directory.

You could, however, create it during application start up and set the permissions.

See [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564154/create-directory-with-write-permissions-for-the-group).

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4117).

Comment: There is an other trick with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, when you are able to set permissions after file process.

Comment: Hi Gary, the folders to be created is dynamic based on the payload in channel. So its not possible for me to do it during context initialization.

Comment: Artem, Can you please detail me on how to use ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice?